# Draw matrix with specific style in TikZ

Tags: nodes, tikz-styles, tikz-matrix

I'm wondering how could I draw a matrix like that:

[image]

I know how to draw a simple matrix:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\matrix (input) [matrix of nodes,
                nodes={rectangle, draw=white, minimum size=.8cm}] at (0,0)
{
|[fill=black]| & |[fill=black!20]|  & |[fill=black!50]|         \\
|[fill=black!50]| & |[fill=black!50]|  & |[fill=black!20]|      \\
|[fill=black!20]| & |[fill=black!20]|  & |[fill=black]|         \\
};
\node [draw,below=8pt] at (input.south) {Sample};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But not how to change it to achieve what I want.

Thank you.

Comment: Normally folks here like that you show what you have already tried - nice. -but you need to add a few lines to make your code compile-able: `\documentclass{... \begin{document}...` and do not write `Thank you`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One answer using the rotation symetry of the figure :

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick, scale=.35]
  \draw[densely dotted, gray, shift={(-4.5,-4.5)}] (0,0) grid +(9,9);
  \draw (-4.5,-4.5) rectangle (4.5,4.5);
  \node {x};
  \foreach[count=\i] \a in {0,1,2,3} {
    \begin{scope}[rotate={90*\a}]
      \draw (4.5,3.5) -| ++(-1,-1) -| ++(-1,-1) -| ++(-1,-1) -- ++(-6,0);
      \path let \n1={int(2*\i-1)}, \n2={int(2*\i)} in (3,1) node{\n1} (2,3) node{\n2};
    \end{scope}
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer. Could you explain me that line `\draw (4.5,3.5) -| ++(-1,-1) -| ++(-1,-1) -| ++(-1,-1) -- ++(-6,0);`? I'm trying to adapt it to reduce the matrix to a 5 x 5 size. I tried `\draw (2.5,1.5) -| ++(-1,-1) -- ++(-4,0);` but I think I misunderstood it.

Comment: @pceccon Your understanding is good ! But you have also to replace all 4.5 by 2.5 and 9 by 5. The only thing that is not clear for me (because I don't know what you want exactly to obtain) is how to modify the number coordinates. Probably `\path let \n1={int(2*\i-1)}, \n2={int(2*\i)} in (2,1) node{\n1} (1,2) node{\n2};` will be ok.

Comment: Hi, @Kpym. After a considerable time, I was asked to paint each of those regions with a specific color. Is it possible to do this adapting your code? Thank you very much.

Comment: @pceccon You can replace the first line (the grid) by something like `\begin{scope}[shift={(-4.5,-4.5)}] \fill[red] (1,2) rectangle +(1,1); \fill[yellow] (4,5) rectangle +(1,1); \draw[densely dotted, gray] (0,0) grid +(9,9); \end{scope}`. In general it is better to ask this kind of questions in a question, not in a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Just playing around (without `tikz`), building up stacked layers of `\Sv` (solid vertical), `\Dv` (dashed vertical), `\Sh` (solid horizontal), `\Dh` (dashed horizontal).  Optional argument on vertical lines provides text following line

Quirks: `\Sd` (solid dot) needed in upper right corner of graph, due to the way I construct things.  and `\intersect` may need to be defined to `{.}` if the `\dashfill` leaves the intersections blank.

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\LN{2ex}
\def\WD{1pt}
\usepackage{stackengine,xcolor,graphicx}

\def\intersect{}% might need it as {.}
\def\dashfill{\cleaders\hbox to 1.43pt{.}\hfill}
\newcommand\dashline[1]{\textcolor{black!50}{\hbox to #1{\dashfill\hfil}}}

\newcommand\Sh{\rule{\LN}{\WD}}

\newcommand\Sd{\rule{\WD}{\WD}}

\newcommand\Sv[1][]{%
  \rule{\WD}{\LN}\kern-\WD\smash{\rule[-\WD]{\WD}{\WD}}\kern-\WD%
    \raisebox{1pt}{\makebox[\LN]{#1}}}

\newcommand\Dh{\dashline{\LN}}

\newcommand\Dv[1][]{\makebox[\WD]{\rotatebox{90}\Dh}\kern-\WD%
    \smash{\makebox[\WD]{\raisebox{-\WD}{\textcolor{black!50}{\intersect}}}}\kern-\WD%
    \raisebox{1pt}{\makebox[\LN]{#1}}}

\setstackgap{S}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\Shortstack[l]{
  \Sh\Sh\Sh\Sh\Sh\Sh\Sh\Sh\Sh\Sd\\
  \Sv\Sv\Dv\Dv\Dv\Sv\Dv\Dv\Dv\Sv\\
  \Dh\Sh\Dh\Dh\Dh\Dh\Dh\Dh\Sh\\
  \Sv\Dv\Sv\Dv[3]\Dv\Sv\Dv[2]\Dv\Sv\Sv\\
  \Dh\Dh\Sh\Dh\Dh\Dh\Dh\Sh\Dh\\
  \Sv\Dv[4]\Dv\Sv\Dv\Sv\Dv\Sv\Dv\Sv\\
  \Dh\Dh\Dh\Sh\Dh\Dh\Sh\Dh\Dh\\
  \Sv\Dv\Dv\Dv\Sv\Sv\Sv\Dv[1]\Dv\Sv\\
  \Sh\Sh\Sh\Sh\Sh\Sh\Dh\Dh\Dh\\
  \Sv\Dv\Dv\Dv\Sv[\scalebox{1.3}{$\,\times$}]\Sv\Dv\Dv\Dv\Sv\\
  \Dh\Dh\Dh\Sh\Sh\Sh\Sh\Sh\Sh\\
  \Sv\Dv[5]\Dv\Sv\Sv\Sv\Dv\Dv\Dv\Sv\\
  \Dh\Dh\Sh\Dh\Dh\Sh\Dh\Dh\Dh\\
  \Sv\Dv\Sv\Dv\Sv\Dv\Sv\Dv[8]\Dv\Sv\\
  \Dh\Sh\Dh\Dh\Dh\Dh\Sh\Dh\Dh\\
  \Sv\Sv\Dv[6]\Dv\Sv\Dv[7]\Dv\Sv\Dv\Sv\\
  \Sh\Dh\Dh\Dh\Dh\Dh\Dh\Sh\Dh\\
  \Sv\Dv\Dv\Dv\Sv\Dv\Dv\Dv\Sv\Sv\\
  \Sh\Sh\Sh\Sh\Sh\Sh\Sh\Sh\Sh
}
\end{document}
```

[image]